# How to add a splashscreen text in a layer-list in Xamarin forms

Tags: xml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

[!I've implemented this splashscreen in android using android studio, but I have switched to xamarin forms for cross-platform, so I want to implement a similar splashscreen in xamarin forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtbFt.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtbFt.jpg)

So far I have been able to add the logo, but I need to add the text, how do I do that?

Here is my splash.xml code in xamarin forms:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item>
    <color android:color="@color/colorBlack"/>
    </item>
    <item>
     <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"
        android:tileMode="disabled"
        android:gravity="center"/>
     </item>


</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

The default SplahScreen does not support adding text.

A quick way to solve it is to `include those version info inside your image`.

Another way is `create a Activity that represents your splash screen`.Then when your SplashActivity is created you start a timer with 3 seconds duration. When those 3 seconds have passed you simply start the main activity for your app.

Layout for `SplashActivity` :

```
  <RelativeLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:gravity="center_vertical" 
   android:background="#fff"
   android:id="@+id/splashview">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src = "@drawable/splash_logo"
    />

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAppVersion"
        android:text="test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:gravity= "bottom"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

And code behind:

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash", MainLauncher =true,NoHistory = true)]
public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof (SplashActivity).Name;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Splash);

        FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtAppVersion).Text = $"Version {PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(PackageName, 0).VersionName}";

    }

    // Launches the startup task
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        Task startupWork = new Task(() => { SimulateStartup(); });
        startupWork.Start();
    }

    // Prevent the back button from canceling the startup process
    public override void OnBackPressed() { }

    // Simulates background work that happens behind the splash screen
    async void SimulateStartup()
    {
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Performing some startup work that takes a bit of time.");
        await Task.Delay(5000); // Simulate a bit of startup work.
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Startup work is finished - starting MainActivity.");
        StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
    }
}
```

I uploaded a sample project [here](https://github.com/XfHua/splash-screen) and you can check.

Comment: Instead of AppCompatActivity it worked with inherting Activity class

Comment: This *kind of* works. Unfortunately, when the app first starts up, it just displays a blank screen while it's loading until it gets around to instantiating the SplashActivity. This results in this splash screen just flashing by to my login screen. If you use the traditional "drawable/splash.xml" method, the splash screen behaves more as expected and comes up when the app first starts loading.